# Questions about maximal and minimal spanning sets

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, is maximal linearly independet and maximal spanning set different terms?
I think i understand what conditions are need to be met when function is a minimal spanning set, but is minimal spanning set always linearly independent? If it is not always linearly independent, then is it always linearly dependent? How about maximal spanning set? is maximal spanning set always linearly independent? If it is not always linearly independent, then is it always linearly dependent?

Dont have to explain why, I think I can hopefully figure things out by myself

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) No they mean the same thing. Part of the definition for a spanning set is that each member of the set is unique, as in it is not a linear combination of another element of the same set. Refer to the proof below to see why a spanning set is, by definition, consisted of unique elements.

2) The minimal spanning set is always linearly independent. Proof:

Assume that $\alpha_i\ne 0$ for i [1, m] and all elements $x_i$ are unique
$$\displaystyle \alpha_1 x_1+\cdots+\alpha_m x_m=0$$
Spans the vector space.
Then that is to say you can write one member of x as a linear combination of the other.

$$x_1=\frac{-\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}x_2+\cdots+\frac{-\alpha_m}{\alpha_1}x_m$$
This results in a contradiction because we assume that all members x are unique. But we have just shown that it is not. Hence, it must be that $\alpha_i = 0$, which means that they are linearly independent.